# How to create a multilingual domain model

Tags: domain-driven-design, multilingual

I am using domain-driven design and I have a pretty clear picture of my domain model. It contains over 120 classes and it is quite stable. We will implement it in .NET 4 and C#. The thing is, we need the model to be multilingual; some of the attributes need to be stored in multiple languages. For example, the Person class has a Position property of type `string` which should store a value in English (e.g. "Librarian") and Spanish (e.g. "Bibliotecario"). The getter for this property should return the English or Spanish version depending on some language parameter.

And here begin my questions. I am not sure how to parameterize this. I have exlpored two major ways to do it:

1. Use property collections. Position would not be a `string` but rather a `Dictionary<Language, string>`, which would let clients retrieve the person's position by language.
2. Keep simple, scalar properties, but make them return (or set) the value for one language or another depending on a globally known "current language" setting. The client code would set the working language, and then all objects would set and get values in that language.

Option 1 avoids global state, but it messes up the interface of almost every class in my model. On the other hand, option 2 is less expressive, since you can't tell what language you're going to get without looking at the global setting. Also, it introduces a dependency into every class on the global setting.

Please note that I am not interested in database or ORM implementations; I am working at the domain model level only.

I have two specific questions then:

- Which is the best option (1 or 2) to achieve my goal of a multilingual domain model?
- Are there other options that I haven't considered, and which are they?

Thank you.

**Edit**. Some have suggested that this is a user interface related issue, and thus can be tackled through globalisation/localisation support in .NET. I disagree. UI localisation works only if you know the localised literals that must be shown to the user at compile time, but this is not our case. My question involves multilingual data that is unknown at compile time, because it will be provided as user data at run-time. This is not a UI-related issue.

**Edit 2**. Please bear in mind that the Person.Position is just a toy example to illustrate the question. It's not part of the real model. Don't try to criticise it or improve upon it; there is no point in doing that. Our business requirements involve a lot of attributes that cannot be encoded as enum types or similar, and must stay as free text. Hence the difficulty.

Comment: What platform are you on? Some have good (?) support for localization and internationalization out of the box.

Comment: .NET 4 and C#. I am familiar with .NET's internationalization support for WinForms, WPF and ASP.NET, but I am not working on the user interface. This is about a domain model only: classes without a visual component.

Comment: I must admit that this sounds strange to me. Why do that for a domain model, if it will not be seen?

Comment: ;-) It will be seen, eventually. Someday we will build a user interface. But now we are building a reusable class library that must be multilingual.

Comment: I find that confusing. A domain model should be concerned with _concepts_ - making the _model_ multi-lingual seems to be bringing in a UI concern to the model.

Comment: It is about concepts, definitely. But concepts are expressed via words, and words are *in a language*. See my example about the person's position. If you model a Person class with a Position property, how do you suggest that we store values there without involving a language?

Comment: That's my point. The concept and concept _name_ is `Position`. When you _retrieve_ the value for it, you use localization.

Comment: Would you post an answer along those lines? Maybe that's an option I haven't considered. Right now I can't wrap my head around it, but please feel free to elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: Does the user need to get/set the p.Position for all languages at the same time (e.g in an Edit Person use case)?

Comment: @georget79: Yes, usually. But not always. Some use case involve setting the values for an object in all the supported languages; others involve looking at the values in one given language.

Comment: @CesarGon If I may ask: What approach did you finally implement, and how did it work out?

Comment: @marapet: Thanks for asking. We ended up implementing a combination of both options 1 and 2 in my OP. It works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the following:

> Some use case involve setting the values for an object in all the
>   supported languages; others involve looking at the values in one given
>   language.

I would suggest going for both options. That means that the Person and all classes that hold multilingual content should keep that content in their state and:

- The Position property should set/get the person's position in the
  **current** user's language.
- There should be a corresponding property or method for **all**
  language setting/getting.
- There should be a method for setting (or even switching if needed)
  the user language. I would create an abstract class (e.g.
  BaseMultilingualEntity) with an abstract SetLanguage(Language
  lang) method and a CurrentLanguage getter. You need to keep
  track of all the objects that derive from BaseMultilingualEntity
  in some sort of registry that would expose language setting.

**EDIT WITH SOME CODE**

```
public enum Language {
    English,
    German
}

// all multilingual entity classes should derive from this one; this is practically a partly implemented observer
public abstract class BaseMultilingualEntity
{
    public Language CurrentLanguage { get; private set; }

    public void SetCurrentLanguage(Language lang)
    {
        this.CurrentLanguage = lang;
    }
}

// this is practically an observable and perhaps SRP is not fully respected here but you got the point i think
public class UserSettings
{
    private List<BaseMultilingualEntity> _multilingualEntities;

    public void SetCurrentLanguage(Language lang)
    {
        if (_multilingualEntities == null)
            return;

        foreach (BaseMultilingualEntity multiLingualEntity in _multilingualEntities)
            multiLingualEntity.SetCurrentLanguage(lang);
    }

    public void TrackMultilingualEntity(BaseMultilingualEntity multiLingualEntity)
    {
        if (_multilingualEntities == null)
            _multilingualEntities = new List<BaseMultilingualEntity>();

        _multilingualEntities.Add(multiLingualEntity);
    }
}

// the Person entity class is a multilingual entity; the intention is to keep the XXXX with the XXXXInAllLanguages property in sync
public class Person : BaseMultilingualEntity
{
    public string Position
    {
        set
        {
            _PositionInAllLanguages[this.CurrentLanguage] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _PositionInAllLanguages[this.CurrentLanguage];
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<Language, string> _PositionInAllLanguages;

    public Dictionary<Language, string> PositionInAllLanguages {
        get
        {
            return _PositionInAllLanguages;
        }
        set
        {
            _PositionInAllLanguages = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        UserSettings us = new UserSettings();
        us.SetCurrentLanguage(Language.English);

        Person person1 = new Person();
        us.TrackMultilingualEntity(person1);

        // use case: set position in all languages
        person1.PositionInAllLanguages = new Dictionary<Language, string> {
            { Language.English, "Software Developer" }, 
            { Language.German, "Software Entwikcler" }
        };

        // use case: display a person's position in the user language
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Position);

        // use case: switch language
        us.SetCurrentLanguage(Language.German);
        Console.WriteLine(person1.Position);

        // use case: set position in the current user's language
        person1.Position = "Software Entwickler";

        // use case: display a person's position in all languages
        foreach (Language lang in person1.PositionInAllLanguages.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine(person1.PositionInAllLanguages[lang]);


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This sounds good; thank you. It closely matches my option 2 in the OP. Would you consider a Model class, for example, to keep track of the language, to which all business objects can have access, rather than the abstract BaseMultilingualEntity?

Comment: @GesarGon i've added some code on my original answer that might shed some light

Comment: Thanks. So, indeed, this is very close to the proposed option 2 in the OP. That's good. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A domain model is an abstraction - it models a specific part of the world, it captures the *concepts* of a domain.

The model exists so developers can communicate in code the way domain experts communicate - using the same names for the same concepts.

Now, a Spanish expert and an English expert may use different words for the same concept, but the concept itself would be the same (one hopes, though language can be ambiguous and people do not always understand the same concept in the same way, but I digress).

The code should pick one human language for these concepts and stick to it. There is absolutely no reason for the model to consist of different languages in order to represent a single concept.

Now, you may need to *show* users of the application data and meta data in their language, but the concept does not change.

In this regard, you second option is the thing you should be doing - with .NET, this is normally done by looking at the `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and/or `CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and by using [satellite assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies.aspx) that will contain localized resources.

Comment: Thanks for putting this as an answer. Maybe I wasn't too clear in writing my question. I agree with you with regard to the *class* model capturing concepts and being relatively language-independent. However, the multilingual aspect appears when we move into the *object* models, i.e. the instances of the class model. The Person class, to use an example, does not change. But instances of it may. In my example, I can set p.Position = "Librarian" or p.Position = "Bibliotecario"; conceptually they say the same thing and represent the same reality, but I am using different languages to do it. (TBC)

Comment: In this regard, I don't see that as a UI-related issue, not at all. Conceptual models are linguistic entities (see e.g. the work of Atkinson & Kühne, or Partridge, or even Agerfalk), and as such they are expressed in a language (natural language, that is). I want mine to be expressed in multiple languages.

Comment: @CesarGon - I don't quite follow. You `p.Position` example would be something that you would localize. Get the strings from a central resource that returns different, localized strings according to the locale (or whatever criteria). This, to me, is not about domain driven design.

Comment: I can't. The strings are not known by us, because they are user data. They are part of the objects that users will instantiate at run time. Hence my reference to object models vs. class model. See it now?

Comment: @CesarGon - I see why you can't use satellite assemblies, but this is still not the responsibility of the domain. This sounds like dynamic data that should be stored and retrieved from a database.

Comment: I agree that the data would be stored and retrieved from a database if we decide to make the model persistent. But the model is not persistent at this stage; it just lives in memory. This shouldn't make a difference; the client code using the model shouldn't care where data is stored. I am interested in overall architectural strategies for implementing the multilingual aspect in the model. I don't care much about storing the data; not yet, anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> My question involves multilingual **data**

[...]

> Please note that I am not interested in database or ORM
>   implementations;

I can see a bit of contradiction in these 2 statements. Whatever the final solution, you'll have multilingual-specific structures in your database anyway as well as a mechanism that queries them to do the translation, right ?

The thing is, unless your domain really is *about* translation, I would try to keep it away from multilingual concerns as much as possible, for the same reason that you would try to make your domain persistence ignorant or UI ignorant.

Thus I would at the very least place the multilingual resolution logic in the Infrastructure layer. You could then for instance use [aspects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to only attach multilingual behavior to some properties, if you really need a trace of multi-language in your entities and don't want your persistence layer to handle all that transparently :

```cs
public class Person
{
   [Multilingual]
   public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no contradiction, unless you have a very limited view of what data or databases are. :-) I intend to use and manage multilingual data in memory, as a network of interconnected domain objects. I am not storing them in a database in the traditional sense, i.e. there won't be a relational or otherwise persistent store, at least by now. So, no contradiction.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to treat multilinguality as an aspect, I agree; that sounds like a good idea. But, unfortunately, that doesn't address my question, which is muuch more specific. Thanks anyway.

Comment: OK, "some of the attributes need to be stored" just clicked to me as "in a (persistent) data store", that's why. I still don't really get what you're trying to achieve. The Person example is somewhat misleading, I suggest you post details and code more specific to your problem.

Comment: Regarding the Person example, I hope it isn't misleading. My question is about architecture and design, rather than a specific domain class. It is expected that people can do some abstraction when devising an answer. Using a real example from our domain would need a few pages of theory about cultural heritage just to convey the semantics of the classes being used, which is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

> It contains over 120 classes and it is quite stable.

Not directly related to question, but you might want to consider the existence of multiple bounded contexts in your domain.

I agree with Oded that it seems in your scenario, language is a UI concern. Sure, the domain may be declared via combination of C# and English, what it represents is abstract. The UI would handle language with [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) - effectively option #2.

A Person entity having a Position property doesn't govern the natural language used to represent the position. You may have a use case where you'd want to display a position in one language while it is originally stored in another. In this case, you can have a translator as part of the UI. This is similar to representing money as a pair of an amount and currency and then converting between currencies.

**EDIT**

> The getter for this property should return the English or Spanish
>   version depending on some language parameter.

What determines this language parameter? What is responsible for ensuring that, say Position, is stored in multiple languages? Or is translation to be performed on the fly? Who is the client of the property? If the client determines the language parameter, why can't the client perform the translation without involving the domain? Are there any  behaviors associated with multiple languages or is this only a concern for reading purposes? The point of DDD is to distill your core behavioral domain and shifts aspects related to querying data into other areas of responsibility. For example, you can use the [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) to access the Position property of an aggregate with a specific language.

Comment: We did consider whether the 120 classes make up one or multiple bounded contexts, but we are pretty sure it is a single one. We have a few complex specialisation hierarchies of research-related concepts; overall, the model does not span that much in terms of conceptual width.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion about how to handle the multilingual aspect, please see my comment to Oded's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Make the User explicit!**
I already encountered domains where the user's culture is a first class citizen in the domain but, in such situations, I model a proper value object (in your example I would use a Position class [properly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20592/Implementing-IEquatable-Properly) implementing `IEquatable<Position>`) and [the User](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/bounded_roles.html) that is able to express such values.

Sticking to your example, something like:

```
public sealed class VATIN : IEquatable<VATIN> { // implementation here... }
public sealed class Position : IEquatable<Position> { // implementation here... }
public sealed class Person 
{ 
    // a few constructors here...

    // a Person's identifier from the domain expert, since it's an entity
    public VATIN Identifier { get { // implementation here } }

    // some more properties if you need them...
    public Position CurrentPosition { get { // implementation here } }

    // some commands
    public void PromoteTo(Position newPosition) { // implementation here }
}
public sealed class User
{
    // <summary>Express the position provided according to the culture of the user.</summary>
    // <param name="position">Position to express.</param>
    // <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="position"/> is null.</exception>
    // <exception cref="UnknownPositionException"><paramref name="position"/> is unknown.</exception>
    public string Express(Position position) { // implementation here }

    // <summary>Returns the <see cref="Position"/> expressed from the user.</summary>
    // <param name="positionName">Name of the position in the culture of the user.</param>
    // <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="positionName"/> is null or empty.</exception>
    // <exception cref="UnknownPositionNameException"><paramref name="positionName"/> is unknown.</exception>
    public Position ParsePosition(string positionName) { // implementation here }
}
```

And don't forget documentation and properly designed [exceptions](http://epic.tesio.it/2013/03/04/exceptions-are-terms-ot-the-ubiquitous-language.html)!

**WARNING**
There are at least two huge design smells in the sample model that you provided:

- a public setter (the Position property)
- a System.String holding business value

A public setter means either that your entity exposes its own state to clients regardless of its own invariants, or that such a property has no business value for the entity and thus should not be part of the entity at all. Indeed, mutable entities should always [separate commands (that can change the state) and queries (that cannot)](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/command_query_separation.html).

A System.String with business semantic always smells of a domain concept left implicit, typically a value-object with equality operations (that implements IEquatable, I mean).

Be aware that a reusable domain model is quite challenging to obtain, since it requires more than two domain experts and a strong experience in ddd modeling. The worst "domain model" that I faced in my carreer was designed by a senior programmer with huge OOP skills but no previous modeling experience: it was a mix of GoF patterns and data structures that, in the hope to be really flexible, proved to be useless. After 200k €, spent in that effort, we had to throw it away and restart from scratch.

May be that you just need a good data model directly mapped to a set of simple data structures in C#: you'll never have any ROI from an upfront investment in a domain model, if you don't really need it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but don't get too carried away by the Position example. It is just that, a toy example to illustrate the question. It's not even part of the real model. Your comments about the smells are thus not applicable. :-)

Comment: The crux of the question is that our business requirements include the handling of free, open text attributes in multiple languages. These attributes cannot be encoded as enum types or similar. Hence the difficulty.

Comment: Well, than you can simply remove the UnknownPositionNameException thrown by ParsePosition. So you can persist the Position (that obviously wrap a string) and enable a backoffice operator to connect those position's description that are related (like "Bibliotecario" and "Librarian").
However, if such freeform texts are not related to business rules, you should move them outside the domain model.

Comment: We are going a bit off topic here, but why can't free text attributes belong in the domain model? Do you have any good reason for that, or any reference to articles or discussion on the matter? Thanks.

Comment: I work with large interacting domain models (split into bounded contexts with hundreds of classes). I've learnt the hard way that everything that is not **strictly** required by the business logic that a class rappresents, will eventually becomes a nightmare during project evolution.  
A DDD project is not like a 3-tiers data driven application with a few workflows.  

Maybe you need to learn it the hard way (like we did) but each bit of data that an entity will contains will make you loose a lot of time and money if it's not needed to ensure business invariants.

Comment: I understand that, but the free text attributes that I am talking about *are* required by our business model. They are a core part of what our business requirements state. Our domain is cultural heritage research, and discursive/narrative information is central. I know this is not the usual enterprise system, so what. :-)

Comment: I suggest you to keep the discursive/narrative informations in a simple data model (directly mapped to a db schema or persisted in a document store), outside the domain. Whenever you need to show the user such informations, a simple query will be eased by using [shared identifiers](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/shared_identifiers.html) for the entities.

Comment: That sounds OK as an implementation decision. But I am interested in what interface the model should show its users (look at the OP). I'll give you an example. Research publications have an abstract which is often translated to various languages. My Publication class could have an Abstract attribute of type string, but I need to make this multilingual. What's the best strategy for the interface? I can store the Abstract narrative text in a separate store under a separate model, that's fine, but how do I integrate that into the Publication class?

Comment: You can't (if the Pubblication class belongs to the domain model). If the Pubblication class is a data structure holding data in one language (or more), that's whole a different story, that probably concerns UI requirements. These classes are often referred as "Projections" or "Read Models" (choose your favorite buzzword here). But don't mix the data design with the domain model. My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth mentioning Apache's *MultiViews* feature and the way it delivers different content based on the browser's *Accept-Language* header.

So if a user requests 'content.xml', for example, Apache will deliver content.en.xml or content.sp.xl or content.fr.xml or whatever is available based on some prioritization rules.

Comment: Well, .NET's satellite assemblies, as mentioned by @Oded, works like that too. But treating this as a localisation issue was ruled out from tyhe beginning, since the strings to be displayed are not known at design time.

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirements I would probably try to model the position as an entity/value on its own. This object would not be a dictionary of translations but rather just be usable as a key into a domainDictionary.

```
// IDomainDictionary would be resolved based on CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
var domainDict = container.Resolve<IDomainDictionary<Position>>();
var position = person.Position;
Debug.Writeline(domainDict.NameFor(position, pluralForm: 1));
```

Now assuming you need to dynamically create new positions when a suitable synonym doesn't exist you could probably keep the data somewhat tidy by using the IDomainDictionary as an source for auto complete suggestions in the UI.